# laravel5.6 How do I update user data after using Request Form validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

professionals.

I can't use form request for user's update action though I tried using form request.
I wanna use form request.

By right, the request form's validation logic is working but after that, the data
 which passed the validation can't be saved.
(There is no errors also, it should be redirected after updated the data.)

When I don't use form request (I write validation logic and validate method in update action directly), the data can be saved after passed the validation.

Here's code...

### UsersController - with validation logic

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function update(Request $request, $user) {

    $user = User::findOrFail($user);

    $request->validate([
            'name'               => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:10',
                'regex: /^[^ -~｡-ﾟ\x00-\x1f\t]+$/u'
            ],
            'name_kana'          => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:20',
                'regex: /^[^ -~｡-ﾟ\x00-\x1f\t]+$/u',
                'regex: /^[ァ-ヶー]+$/u'
            ],
            'email'              => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
            ],
            'email_confirmation' => [
                'required',
                'same:email'
            ],
            'birth_day'          => [
                'required',
                'date'
            ],
            'address'            => [
                'required',
                'max:40',
                'regex: /^[^ -~｡-ﾟ\x00-\x1f\t]+$/u'
            ],
            'job_type_id'        => [
                'required'
            ],
        ]
    );

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->name_kana = $request->name_kana;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->birth_day = $request->birth_day;
    $user->address = $request->address;
    $user->job_type_id = $request->job_type_id;

    $user->save();

    return redirect('users/')->with('message', '情報を編集しました');
}
```

### UsersController - using Form Request

```
use App\Http\Requests\UserProfileUpdateRequest;

public function update(UserProfileUpdateRequest $request, $user) {

    $user = User::findOrFail($user);

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->name_kana = $request->name_kana;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->birth_day = $request->birth_day;
    $user->address = $request->address;
    $user->job_type_id = $request->job_type_id;

    $user->save();

    return redirect('users/')->with('message', '情報を編集しました');
}
```

### Form Request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
// email項目で自分を無視するときにundefined $userの回避のため
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserProfileUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    // email項目で自分を無視するときにundefined $userの回避のため
    $user = Auth::user();

    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:10|
                   regex:/^[^ -~｡-ﾟ\x00-\x1f\t]+$/u',

        'name_kana' => 'required|string|max:20|
                        regex:/^[^ -~｡-ﾟ\x00-\x1f\t]+$/u|
                        regex:/^[ァ-ヶー]+$/u',

        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email',
                    Rule::unique("users")->ignore($user->id)],

        'email_confirmation' => 'required|email|same:email',

        'birth_day' => 'required|date',

        'address' => 'required|max:40|
                      regex:/^[^ -~｡-ﾟ\x00-\x1f\t]+$/u',

        'job_type_id' => 'required',

        'password' => 'required|min:4|max:8|
                       regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/u',
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot save when using default `Request` class ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: Did you get any  error

Comment: There is no error (just work Form request's validation, after that, nothing happen... It should be redirected after updated the data).

I mean only when I don't use Request Form, the data is updated but when I use Request Form, the data isn't updated though the Request Form validation is working.

Comment: Which one is working and which is not working, please clarify by stating that this one is working and this one is not.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I edited my English.
And "UsersController - with validation logic" is working properly, but "UsersController - using Form Request" is not working...

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
return redirect('/users')->with('message', '情報を編集しました');
```

Not:

```
return redirect('users/')->with('message', '情報を編集しました');
```

Comment: @Bob, I tried your code, but situation is not change.
Anyway I should fix the redirect part, thanks for your help :)

And I checked the database updating because I thought that data updating is done, but just redirecting is not working.
But both are not done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to capture the validated data in a variable:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate(...);
```

(as specified in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)).

The `validate()` method will return all sanitized data after its check, so you will to capture this return.

Afterwards, save the fields to the record using the new variable:

```
$user->name = $validatedData->name;
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried your way but still it doesn't work...
I thought you are right and this is exactly my mistake...